# FPT vs W[P] - Parameterized Complexity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, parameterized-complexity, fixed-parameter-tractable

In parametrized complexity, $\mathsf{FPT} \subseteq \mathsf{W}[1]$ $\subseteq \mathsf{W}[2]$ $\subseteq \ldots \subseteq \mathsf{W}[P]$. It is conjectured that each of the containments is proper.

If $\mathsf{FPT}=\mathsf{W}[P]$ then $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{W}[P]$.

But does it follow that

- If $\mathsf{FPT}=\mathsf{W}[1]$ then $\mathsf{FPT}=\mathsf{W}[P]$ ?
  or
- If $\mathsf{W}[t-1]=\mathsf{W}[t]$ (for some t) then $\mathsf{FPT}=\mathsf{W}[P]$ ?

Comment: What does the "W[]" notation mean?

Comment: Does the second question mean "for all t" or "for some t"?

Comment: The second question mean "for some t"

Comment: You are not being a helpful question-asker.  You haven't included definition or links to the W-hierarchy, even though someone asked you about that.  The answer to your questions is probably "both are open," because of the W-hierarchy's characterization as families of modified AC0 circuits -- a collapse of the W-hierarchy would imply a circuit complexity collapse.  (This is considered evidence that every level of the W-hierarchy is a proper subset of the next.)  But I would have to check some things to post an answer (not my area), and you are not taking the question seriously.

Comment: A parameterized problem (L,K) belongs to W[t] if there exists k' computed from k such that
(L,K) reduces to the weight-k' satisability problem for weft-t circuits. [Downey, 1997]


**[Downey, 1997] Rodney G. Downey, Michael R. Fellows, Kenneth W. Regan; Research Report Series Parameterized Circuit Complexity and the W Hierarchy; Centre for Discrete Mathematics and Theoretical Computer Science; 1997.**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This question is tricky as the answer (as far as I know) is still "don't know".

To add some weight to this, Flum & Grohe [1] give as open problems (p. 164):

> - Is the $\mathrm{W}$-hierarchy strict under the assumption $\mathrm{FPT} \neq \mathrm{W[P]}$?
> - For $t \geq 1$, does the equality $\mathrm{W}[t] = \mathrm{W}[t + 1]$ imply $\mathrm{W}[t] = \mathrm{W}[t + 2]$?

Moreover, in Downey and Fellow's recent monograph [2] the strongest (outright) statement they make is (p. 521):

> A more subtle hypothesis is that the $\mathrm{W}$-hierarchy is proper, and, in particular, $\mathrm{W}[1] \neq \mathrm{W}[2]$.

There is no following (or later) statement along the lines "otherwise the $\mathrm{W}$-hierarchy would collapse", or similar.

This is also preceded by:

> A weaker hypothesis might be that for some $t$,
>   $$\mathrm{FPT} \neq \mathrm{W}[t]$$

Implying that it is possible that $\mathrm{FPT} = \mathrm{W}[t-1]$ with no other effects on the hierarchy.

**References:**

1. J. Flum and M. Grohe, "Parameterized Complexity Theory", Springer, 2006.
2. R. Downey and M. Fellows, "Fundamentals of Parameterized Complexity Theory", Springer, 2014.