# What are the consequences if $W[i]=W[i-1]$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, big-picture, fixed-parameter-tractable

$FPT=W[1]$ does not collapse the $W$ hierarchy however falsifies $ETH$ belief. Is there non-trivial consequence if $W[i]=W[i-1]$ and any other consequence at $W[1]$?

Comment: What is W? What is FPT?

Comment: Duplicate of https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8074/fpt-vs-wp-parameterized-complexity

Comment: @Gamow There 'W[t]=W[t-1] implies W[P]=FPT' is asked and here it is more general.

Comment: @Turbo: Perhaps you could update your question and state precisely what it is that you would like to know and that is not already contained in the answer to the older question.